# Extract data from python to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following code

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

api = PushshiftAPI()

start_time = int(datetime.datetime(2021,3,16).timestamp())

submissions = api.search_submissions(after=start_time,
                                         subreddit='wallstreetbets',
                                         filter=['url','author','title','subreddit'])

for submission in submissions:
    #print(submission.created_utc)
    #print(submission.title)
    #print(submission.url)
    
    words = submission.title.split()
    cashtags = list(set(filter(lambda word: word.lower().startswith('$'), words)))

    if len(cashtags) > 0:
        print(cashtags)
        print(submission.created_utc)
        print(submission.title)
        print(submission.url)
```

I would like to export the data into an excel file, but I am having problems with it. Can you guys help? I have seen a lot of people use 'pandas' but I can't really get it to work.

Comment: when I ran your code, the cashtags list didn't get filled with any data

Comment: I get a lot of data output in the shell when running the code, but I can't get that extracted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, and the cashtags list is empty so I write `try... except` for this part in case this problem is just happen to me. the rest of the data is saved in the excel file as it should. check the code below:

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
import datetime
import openpyxl
import os

def save_submissions(submissions_file, submissions):

    
    wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(submissions_file)
    sheet = wb.active
    
    num = 1
    sheet["A"+str(num)] = "created_utc"
    sheet["B"+str(num)] = "title"
    sheet["C"+str(num)] = "url"
    sheet["D"+str(num)] = "cashtags"
    
    for submission in submissions:

        num += 1
        sheet["A"+str(num)] = submission.created_utc
        sheet["B"+str(num)] = submission.title
        sheet["C"+str(num)] = submission.url
        
        try:
            words = submission.title.split() 
            cashtags = list(set(filter(lambda word: word.lower().startswith('$'), words)))
            
            sheet["D"+str(num)] = cashtags
        except:
            continue
    wb.save(submissions_file)



api = PushshiftAPI()

start_time = int(datetime.datetime(2021,3,16).timestamp())

submissions = api.search_submissions(after=start_time,
                                         subreddit='wallstreetbets',
                                         filter=['url','author','title','subreddit'])

        
#create excell file
cwd = os.getcwd()
submissions_file = os.path.join(cwd, 'submissions.xlsx')
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb.save(submissions_file)

save_submissions(submissions_file, submissions)
```

Comment: You are a legend - THANK YOU! The code works perfect! I have tried to make it only get the submissions in which the title includes "GME", but it doesn't work. Do you have the code for that too?

Comment: glad it worked. for " have tried ..... "GME, but it doesn't work. " this is another question should be asked separately.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe I can rewrite the cashtags line, so I just get all the submissions, and then I can filter it afterwards?

Comment: good luck, if my answer met your expectations please select it as accepted answer.